# Adding esp32_komoot_ble library to Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32

I am an absolute beginner with Arduino IDE and I want to build an interesting device I stumbled upon on github
https://github.com/jstiefel/esp32_komoot_ble
Problem is I really can not add it to Arduino IDE. I did the wiring for the lcd and all, but please bear in mind i'm an electrician, with a very basic understanding of arduino/ absolute beginner. 
What i'm asking is which is  the "main file" in the src folder so i can rename it 'ino' to work with the arduino IDE  and upload it to the esp32 board?
I downloaded the esp32 library and all the dependencies that says in the readme.md file. I download the esp32_komoot_ble.zip file. Now how do I get the  .cpp and .h files on the arduino IDE and finally my esp32 device. I have been watching tutorial for 1 week now  but could not figure it out yet!
Thank you for everything guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file, that you are searching, is the one, which contains the `setup()` and `loop` functions: `esp32_komoot_ble.cpp`

These functions are part of the Arduino framework and wrap the classic `main()` function. `setup()` is called once at startup, `loop()` after it repeating forever.

Comment: Tank you so much mate! I'm waiting for 'arduino for dummies' book ordered from amazon. Gotta start somewhere, right? Thank you again!